# how to modify the type of the child chart in linked fusion chart?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

By default, the child chart will follow the type of the parent chart in my case the parent chart is bar2d. my child chart i want to display as line chart. how to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `configureLink` method.

```
myChart.configureLink({
    type: 'pie2d', // Set the linked-charts configuration to load all linked charts as Pie
    width: '80%', // The width of the charts would be 80% of their parent container
    overlayButton: {
        message: ' X ', // Set the button to show letter "X"
        bgColor:'#999999',
        borderColor: '#cccccc'
    }
});
```

http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-methods.html#configureLink